# Create Azure container instance from code without Fluent

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am upgrading an Azure function from v3 to v4. Part of that upgrade is replacing the Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerInstance.Fluent package (which is deprecated) with Azure.ResourceManager.ContainerInstance.

I currently create the container instance using the following code:

```
            var containerGroup = azure.ContainerGroups.Define(containerGroupName)
            .WithRegion(azureRegion)
            .WithExistingResourceGroup(resourceGroupName)
            .WithLinux()
            .WithPrivateImageRegistry(registryServer, registryUsername, registryPassword)
            .WithoutVolume()
            .DefineContainerInstance(containerInstanceName)
                .WithImage(containerImage)
                .WithExternalTcpPort(int.Parse(Config.ContainerTcpPort))
                .WithCpuCoreCount(double.Parse(Config.ContainerCpuCoreCount))
                .WithMemorySizeInGB(double.Parse(Config.ContainerMemorySize))
                .WithEnvironmentVariables(envVars)
                .Attach()
            .WithDnsPrefix(containerGroupName)
            .WithRestartPolicy(ContainerGroupRestartPolicy.Never)
            .Create();
```

How do I create a container instance using the Azure.ResourceManager.ContainerInstance package?

Comment: Check this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/resourcemanager.containerinstance-readme?view=azure-dotnet) QuickStart Examples for creating ACRs using Azure.ResourceManager.ContainerInstance

Comment: @Desari Kamali, I have looked at that document but I'm not sure which class to use. Have you created a container instance using these classes?

Comment: I have not found a class with a method to create a container instance. I feel that it must be there, but I'm just not finding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create a Container Instance using Azure.ResourceManager.ContainerInstance

> You can make use of the complete code in this [**Github  Repository**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Azure.ResourceManager.ContainerInstance_1.1.0-beta.3/sdk/containerinstance/Azure.ResourceManager.ContainerInstance/samples/Generated/Samples/Sample_ContainerGroupCollection.cs)

> Refer this section from above [**Github repository**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Azure.ResourceManager.ContainerInstance_1.1.0-beta.3/sdk/containerinstance/Azure.ResourceManager.ContainerInstance/samples/Generated/Samples/Sample_ContainerGroupCollection.cs)
> code to Create Container Instance:-
>
> ```cs
> using System; 
> using System.Collections.Generic; 
> using System.Threading.Tasks;
> using Azure; using Azure.Core;
> using Azure.Identity; 
> using Azure.ResourceManager; 
> using Azure.ResourceManager.ContainerInstance; 
> using Azure.ResourceManager.ContainerInstance.Models; using Azure.ResourceManager.Models; 
> using Azure.ResourceManager.Resources;
>
> namespace Azure.ResourceManager.ContainerInstance.Samples {
>     public partial class Sample_ContainerGroupCollection
>     {
>         static async Task Main(string[] args)
>         {
>         }
>
>             // ContainerGroupCreateWithExtensions
>             [NUnit.Framework.Test]
>             [NUnit.Framework.Ignore("Only verifying that the sample builds")]
>             public async Task CreateOrUpdate_ContainerGroupCreateWithExtensions()
>             {
>                 // Generated from example definition: specification/containerinstance/resource-manager/Microsoft.ContainerInstance/preview/2022-10-01-preview/examples/ContainerGroupExtensions.json
>                 // this example is just showing the usage of "ContainerGroups_CreateOrUpdate" operation, for the dependent
> resources, they will have to be created separately.
>
>                 // get your azure access token, for more details of how Azure SDK get your access token, please refer to
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/authentication?tabs=command-line
>                 TokenCredential cred = new DefaultAzureCredential();
>                 // authenticate your client
>                 ArmClient client = new ArmClient(cred);
>
>                 // this example assumes you already have this ResourceGroupResource created on azure
>                 // for more information of creating ResourceGroupResource, please refer to the document of
> ResourceGroupResource
>                 string subscriptionId = "<subscription-id>";
>                 string resourceGroupName = "<rg-name>";
>                 ResourceIdentifier resourceGroupResourceId = ResourceGroupResource.CreateResourceIdentifier(subscriptionId,
> resourceGroupName);
>                 ResourceGroupResource resourceGroupResource = client.GetResourceGroupResource(resourceGroupResourceId);
>
>                 // get the collection of this ContainerGroupResource
>                 ContainerGroupCollection collection = resourceGroupResource.GetContainerGroups();
>
>                 // invoke the operation
>                 string containerGroupName = "valley12";
>                 ContainerGroupData data = new ContainerGroupData(new AzureLocation("eastus2"), new ContainerInstanceContainer[]
>                 { new ContainerInstanceContainer("demo1","nginx",new ContainerResourceRequirements(new
> ContainerResourceRequestsContent(1.5,1))) { Command = { }, Ports = {
> new ContainerPort(80) }, EnvironmentVariables = { }, }
>                 }, ContainerInstanceOperatingSystemType.Linux)
>                 {
>                     ImageRegistryCredentials = { },
>                     IPAddress = new ContainerGroupIPAddress(new ContainerGroupPort[]
>                 { new ContainerGroupPort(80) { Protocol = ContainerGroupNetworkProtocol.Tcp, }
>                 }, ContainerGroupIPAddressType.Private),
>                     SubnetIds = { new ContainerGroupSubnetId(new ResourceIdentifier("/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<rg-name>/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/<v-net>/subnets/<subnet-name>"))
> },
>                     Extensions = { new DeploymentExtensionSpec("kube-proxy") { ExtensionType = "kube-proxy",
> Version = "1.0", Settings = BinaryData.FromObjectAsJson(new
> Dictionary<string, object>() { ["clusterCidr"] = "10.240.0.0/16",
> ["kubeVersion"] = "v1.9.10"}), ProtectedSettings =
> BinaryData.FromObjectAsJson(new Dictionary<string, object>() {
> ["kubeConfig"] = "<kubeconfig encoded string>"}), },new
> DeploymentExtensionSpec("vk-realtime-metrics") { ExtensionType =
> "realtime-metrics", Version = "1.0", } },
>                 };
>                 ArmOperation<ContainerGroupResource> lro = await collection.CreateOrUpdateAsync(WaitUntil.Completed,
> containerGroupName, data);
>                 ContainerGroupResource result = lro.Value;
>
>                 // the variable result is a resource, you could call other operations on this instance as well
>                 // but just for demo, we get its data from this resource instance
>                 ContainerGroupData resourceData = result.Data;
>                 // for demo we just print out the id
>                 Console.WriteLine($"Succeeded on id: {resourceData.Id}");
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

**Code For Get Container from above repository:-**

> ```cs
> // Licensed under the MIT License.
>
> // <auto-generated/>
>
> #nullable disable
>
> using System; 
> using System.Collections.Generic;
> using System.Threading.Tasks;
> using Azure; 
> using Azure.Core; 
> using Azure.Identity; 
> using Azure.ResourceManager; 
> using Azure.ResourceManager.ContainerInstance; 
> using Azure.ResourceManager.ContainerInstance.Models; using Azure.ResourceManager.Models;
> using Azure.ResourceManager.Resources;
>
> namespace Azure.ResourceManager.ContainerInstance.Samples {
>     public partial class Sample_ContainerGroupCollection
>     {
>         static async Task Main(string[] args)
>         {
>         }
>         // ContainerGroupsListByResourceGroup
>         [NUnit.Framework.Test]
>         [NUnit.Framework.Ignore("Only verifying that the sample builds")]
>         public async Task GetAll_ContainerGroupsListByResourceGroup()
>         {
>             // Generated from example definition: specification/containerinstance/resource-manager/Microsoft.ContainerInstance/preview/2022-10-01-preview/examples/ContainerGroupsListByResourceGroup.json
>             // this example is just showing the usage of "ContainerGroups_ListByResourceGroup" operation, for the dependent
> resources, they will have to be created separately.
>
>             // get your azure access token, for more details of how Azure SDK get your access token, please refer to
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/authentication?tabs=command-line
>             TokenCredential cred = new DefaultAzureCredential();
>             // authenticate your client
>             ArmClient client = new ArmClient(cred);
>
>             // this example assumes you already have this ResourceGroupResource created on azure
>             // for more information of creating ResourceGroupResource, please refer to the document of ResourceGroupResource
>             string subscriptionId = "<subscription-id>";
>             string resourceGroupName = "<rg-name>";
>             ResourceIdentifier resourceGroupResourceId = ResourceGroupResource.CreateResourceIdentifier(subscriptionId,
> resourceGroupName);
>             ResourceGroupResource resourceGroupResource = client.GetResourceGroupResource(resourceGroupResourceId);
>
>             // get the collection of this ContainerGroupResource
>             ContainerGroupCollection collection = resourceGroupResource.GetContainerGroups();
>
>             // invoke the operation and iterate over the result
>             await foreach (ContainerGroupResource item in collection.GetAllAsync())
>             {
>                 // the variable item is a resource, you could call other operations on this instance as well
>                 // but just for demo, we get its data from this resource instance
>                 ContainerGroupData resourceData = item.Data;
>                 // for demo we just print out the id
>                 Console.WriteLine($"Succeeded on id: {resourceData.Id}");
>             }
>
>             Console.WriteLine($"Succeeded");
>         }
>
>     }
>    }
> ```

**Output:-**

[image]